# Eclipse Plugin Trust authorities issue

Tags: eclipse

I had tried to install a plugin in the eclipse environment, the problem is not with the installation but right after that installation a sub window is getting opened and its title is Trust Authorities.

In the trust authorities window, I have to click on trust selected button but its disabled even after selecting trust all the authorities. So, help me out with this issue.

Comment: But did you select the authorities first? You are talking about the following, right? https://youtu.be/OQe_hafeuz8?t=539 Checking _Always trust all authorities_ means don't care about security not at all. This is not recommended, but the worst thing you can do.

Comment: Thank you @howlger for responding but the thing is that I selected the trust all authorities as a last resort. As I find the button being disabled. But don't worry, I will reinstall the Eclipse application.

Comment: Your question does not say this and also does not show the dialog. If it is a malfunction, which I doubt, it is up to you to prove it with an exact step-by-step instructions on how to reproduce it and a screenshot.

Comment: Same behavior under MacOS. Cannot click "Trust Selected" :(

Comment: @LiMar Be the first to tell how this can be reproduced. Did you hit the _Select All_ button?

Comment: @howlger Ok, found the problem/solution (another thread on SO). No select/deselect would help here. The problem is in one of the update sites, it's either unresponsive or giving some error (to the internal Eclipse machinery I mean). So the solution is to clean up the "Available Software Sites" list manually, looking for old/outdated/suspicious/recently-installed plug-ins and such. Once the problematic one removed, the Trust Selected can be activated as designed - by selecting the authorities...

Answer (score 4):

[image: I guess I have the same issue]

Complementing the question presented, I'm putting how this issue appears:  the button "Trusted Selected" is disabled, for no reason.

This was taken from Eclipse 2023-03 (4.27.0)

**EDITED:**

In my case, it was solved with an IDE upgrade. Seems the build 2023-06 (4.28.0) solved the issue.

**EDITED #2:**

I've just figured out that some Eclipse plug-in mess up Eclipse's Install/Update module. In my case, it was the Tabnine plugin.

You must go to the menu "Window" -> "Preferences" -> "Install/Update" -> "Available Software Sites" and then remove/disable the troubling plug-in site.

Comment: You can fix the Tabnine Eclipse plugin snafu by going to Window->Preferences->Install/Update->Trust and then selecting the "Authorities" tab and the click "Add" and then paste https://eclipse-update-site.tabnine.com and then select 'Apply and Close'.  Found solution at https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tabnine-ai-assistant-chat-software-developers#errors